# Dart SDK build failed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: dart, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to build the Dart SDK on the Raspberry Pi platform following the instruction [here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/RaspberryPi).

I'm compiling from Raspbian using the qemu emulator.

The build works until I get this exception:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/dart/dart/out/ReleaseARM/lib.host:/home/pi/dart/dart/out/ReleaseARM/lib.target:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; cd runtime; mkdir -p /home/pi/dart/dart/out/ReleaseARM/obj/gen; python -u ../tools/make_version.py --output "/home/pi/dart/dart/out/ReleaseARM/obj/gen/version.cc" --input vm/version_in.cc
make_version.py exception
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
make: *** [out/ReleaseARM/obj/gen/version.cc] Error 255
BUILD FAILED
```

I've checked and the file version.cc does not exists in the specified folder.

Comment: Do you compile ON the raspberry pi? As far as I know is a dedicated linux system required and the output copied to the raspberry pi.

Comment: I'm compiling in a Raspbian instance running in an emulator. I've tried cross-compiling but without success (the build complete but the executable don't run).

Comment: I think only cross compiling works. But you also have to find a SVN revision that works at all.

Comment: Most of the build has been completed with no problem, the missing file I don't think is related to the architecture or OS hosting the compilation. The cross compiling produces an executable that give me an error of "file not found". I will retry also cross compiling and then I will post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this [comment](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21611#c5) the direct compilation in the Raspbian env is currently not tested or supported.